# abelian subgroups of $GL(2,\mathbb{Z}_p)$

Tags: group-theory

Is there a classification of abelian subgroups of $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$? or $GL(2,\mathbb{Z}_p)$?

Here $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the ring of $p$-adic integers.

Comment: For abelian subgroups of $GL(2,p)$ see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431888/abelian-subgroups-of-gl-n-mathbbf-p?rq=1).

Comment: For $\Bbb{Z}_p$ there are other abelian subgroups. For example if $K$ is the quadratic unramified extension of $\Bbb{Q}_p$, then its ring of integers $\mathcal{O}$ is a free $\Bbb{Z}_p$ module of rank two, and its group of units $\mathcal{O}^*$ is then surely acting faithfully on it, and can thus be embedded into $GL_2(\Bbb{Z}_p)$.

Comment: Do you denote by $\mathbb{Z}_p$ the $p$-adic integers, or the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ ? The notation $GL(2,p)$ refers to the finite field.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think he means $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Regarding *finite* abelian subgroups of $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$ there is a classification, see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/55995/finite-subgroup-of-gl-2c).

Comment: @DietrichBurde by $\mathbb{Z}_p$ I meant the $p$-adic integers.